# How do I get a serialized array of values using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

What I need to have is a serialized array of data after the sort. I am using tables so I'm not sure how to get this array. No matter what I try, all I am able to get is a blank alert.

Just to clarify, what I need is to have a serialized array after the user has preformed their sort.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {        
    $("#articles tbody").sortable({
        connectWith: 'td',
        stop: function(){
          var string = $("#articles tbody").sortable("serialize");
          alert( string);
        }
    });
  });

<table id="articles" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="498">
      <td>498</td>
      <td>498</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="497">
      <td>497</td>
      <td>497</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="496">
      <td>496</td>
      <td>496</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="495">
      <td>495</td>
      <td>495</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: RTM http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

Comment: j08691, thank you for pointing me to the right place in the manual. I'm really new to JQ. I think I may be OK from here.

Comment: Sweet Joy!! Thank you j08691!